# "CL Typing Label " library error in swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uilabel, typing

I have added the file "CLTypingLabel.swift" from folder CLTypingLabel-master -> Pod -> Classes -> CLTypingLabel.swift to my xcode project taken from https://github.com/l800891/CLTypingLabel
 and when I build the project there shows 38 errors....

Some errors are

1. Consecutive declarations on a line must be seperated by ';'
2. Expected declarations
3. Use of unresolved identifiers 'DispatchQueue'

How should I rectify it or Is there any easy label library to animate as message typing  while displaying the label?

Comment: next time you could open an issue directly on my repository ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be, that you are trying to use a Swift 3.0 library in a Swift 2.x project?

Comment: Ya Correct @retendo.. Is there any way to convert to Swift 3.0 to Swift 2.x ? or is there any other library file similar to CL Typing Label in  Swift 2.x compatible?

Comment: This is the library file prior to the Swift 3.0 conversion: https://github.com/l800891/CLTypingLabel/blob/0c1913c95c6e4dc2ed01b52d2a027fbdb4c04d2a/Pod/Classes/CLTypingLabel.swift